# 301 PHP redirect error - from variable

Tags: php, http-status-code-301

I am writing a 301 redirect, but getting an error when I pass the url through a variable

I use this script to get the current page URL and Domain name.

```
<?php
$mainurl = "http://" .$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$pagename1 = "".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
?>
```

If the page does not redirect I use this to redirect the page.

```
<?php if ($row_rs_page['g_page_url'] != $pagename1) 
       $pagenameexists = "<p>page exists</p>";
?>
<?php Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
      Header("Location: ".$mainurl."");
?>
```

This is where I suspect the problem occurs: `Header("Location: ".$mainurl."");` If I type in http://www.example.com in the place of $mainurl the page redirects as it should. If I use the dynamic variable it throughs an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I have included the url which redirects to a page that does not exists: http://24hour-casino-games.com/index1.asp I do not see an error message

Comment: the error says you are trying to open a file which does not exist !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$mainurl = "http://" .$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$pagename1 = "".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];

if ($row_rs_page['g_page_url'] != $pagename1) 
   $pagenameexists = "<p>page exists</p>";
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
  Header("Location: ".$mainurl."");
?>
```

Shakti is right !
Do not echo anything before the LOCATION header

Comment: Interesting I have changed the code to <?php if ($row_rs_page['g_page_url'] != $pagename1) { Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); Header("Location: ".$mainurl.""); }?> and now it seems to work 100% thanks for the input!

Comment: Actually, do not output ANYTHING before ANY header. Headers are sent before page content, when you output anything (directly), headers won't work correctly. In this case, use output buffering.